# Find the solution of $x(x^2-y^2-z^2)dx-2xydy+2xz=0$

Tags: linear-pde

Solve $ 
x(x^2-y^2-z^2)dx-2xydy+2xz=0$ using Lagrange multipliers. I was able to find only one solution by making use of the last two fractions in Lagrange auxiliary equations.

Comment: Please. Show your efforts.

Comment: Taking last two fractions of Lagrange auxilary equations $\frac{dy}{-2xy}=\frac{dz}{-2xz}$, we can find one solution as $y=cz$, for some constant $c$. I could not able to find any set of multipliers to find another solutions